# Java 8 How to exclude optional parts when using DateTimeFormatter#format

Tags: java, java-8, date-format

I'm using the Java 8 `DateTimeFormatter` with a pattern that has an optional part and I want that optional part to be excluded when formatting to `String`

The pattern I am using: `yyyyMMddHHmmss[.SSS]Z`

How I'm using my `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss[.SSS]Z");
String formattedDate = df.format(zonedDateTime);
```

I'm expecting the result to be: `20180606052500+0100`

Instead of: `20180606052500.000+0100`

A solution would be to use two `DateTimeFormatter` but I don't want that as I want my `DateTimeFormatter` to be statically defined in one place so it can be reused for both parsing and formatting.

Comment: why don't you use two formatters? one for reading with the optional part and one for writing (in the format you want to write)? It probably can't get any easier than this?

Comment: I actually want to have 1 place in my code where I define a `DateTimeFormatter` and reuse that one for all my parsing and formatting

Comment: you can still have 1 place.... but with 2 formatters... what you want screams for 2 formatters... why do you want to have only one? If it did support that, will that really be more readable? You can also build your own wrapper if it doesn't... still: is that worth it? wouldn't it also be worth it to have one formatter that clearly states (in the naming) that it's the format you use for export/writing and one that clearly shows which formats are allowed for read/import?

Comment: Actually the reason why I'm looking for a solution with only 1 `DateTimeFormatter` is because currently our application doesn't support the fraction as optional part. So there is a change requested to accept dates containing fractions but still format without.

If I could change the DateTimeFormatter in a way to exclude the optional part when formatting I only need to do the change in one place instead of changing the DateTimeFormatter everywhere else

Comment: Sometimes change requests require us to redesign our applications... don't always try to use the "easy/short route"... I have seen a lot of legacy code (... we even write legacy code now ;-)) and many of those short/easy solutions are not that easily understandable when you look at the code now... you support now 2 different formats as input... but you write only 1... so... best advice I can give you: use at least two formatters...

Comment: You could wrap/convert your `zonedDateTime` into another instance of `TemoralAccessor` which does not [provide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html#isSupported-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) data for sub-second fields ([MILLI_OF_SECOND](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MILLI_OF_SECOND) &c.).

Comment: I think what Roland is saying makes sense. It would indeed make it less understandable if we would have one `DateTimeFormatter`for different use cases. I'll refactor the code so that I have an abstraction and when parsing will use the one with optional and when formatting I'll use the one without

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to reuse the common part of the pattern for building 2 different formats:

```
private static final String META_FORMAT = "yyyyMMddHHmmss%sZ";
private static final DateTimeFormatter FOR_PARSING = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String.format(META_FORMAT, "[.SSS]"));
private static final DateTimeFormatter FOR_FORMATTING = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String.format(META_FORMAT, ""));
```

This way you have no duplicate pattern.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `appendFraction` method:

```
    DateTimeFormatter df = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
            .appendFraction(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0, 3, true)
            .appendPattern("Z")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("20180606052500+0100", df);
    String formattedDate = df.format(odt);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output is:

> 20180606052500+0100

So the code has parsed the variant without fractional seconds and formatted back in the same way. If it parses `"20180606052500.000+0100"`, it still will not print the fraction. With `"20180606052500.125+0100"` it also prints `20180606052500.125+0100`, that is, with the fraction.

I also tried with `"20180606052500.100+0100"` and got `20180606052500.1+0100`. So in this case it prints one decimal. You might have wanted three decimals in this case, I don’t know. `appendFraction` accepts a minimum and maximum number of decimals, but there is no way to specify that 3 decimals are preferred over 1 or 2.

If you *never* want to print any fraction, no matter if it is zero or non-zero, use:

```
    String formattedDate = df.format(odt.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

PS Since you don’t have a time zone (like Australia/Hobart), use `OffsetDateTime` for your date-time, not `ZonedDateTime`.

Document link: [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendFraction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendFraction(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,int,int,boolean))

Comment: I indeed want three decimals when a fraction is known.
I suppose this isn't possible if I pass minWidth of 3?

Comment: I doubt that any one formatter can give you that, even if you use it for formatting alone (and not for parsing). I’d use two formatters and `if (odt.get(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND) == 0)` to decide which of them to use.

Comment: I think the parsing isn't the problem... the optional part will work for that... but formatting/writing is the problem... you can not use `minWidth=3` or otherwise you are expecting 3 digits there... so still... use two formatters ;-)

Comment: I'm indeed going for the solution where I have two DateTimeFormatters and will use the one without the fraction to format

Comment: @OleV.V. note that I only updated your code, because it gets more readable that way on mobile... i.e. the relevant part (code) is visible right from the beginning and you do not need to scroll right ;-) this just as a side-note... it's not a tabs-vs-spaces-thing ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Roland. I like my code a slight bit indented, but then again, I am using a 24" monitor and no mobile device. What you say makes sense.

Comment: on work it's the same for me... but since I occasionally look up things on mobile as well, I realised that it sometimes really is cumbersome to read code that way... unfortunately: longer lines will never be really as readable on mobile ;-)